# mysql error with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

i am trying to create an sample apps using GWT and my code is below

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
  VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
  MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();
  database data=new database();
     Statement s1;
    try {
        s1 = data.conn.createStatement();
         s1.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM details LIMIT 10");
           ResultSet rs = s1.getResultSet ();
           while (rs.next ())
           {


               String name = rs.getString ("name");
               oracle.add(name);
           }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    SuggestBox suggestbox = new SuggestBox(oracle);
    panel.add(new Label("Enter Country"));
    panel.add(suggestbox);
    panel.addStyleName("demo-panel-padded");
    RootPanel.get("demo").add(panel);
```

}
and i have added the mysql-bin.jar connector in `war/WEB_INF/lib/` and now i am getting an compilation error

```
17:39:52.353 [ERROR] [a] Line 28: No source code is available for type java.sql.Statement; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

i need to know why i am getting this error and how can i rectify it

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use server-side code (java.sql.* in your case) in GWT client side modules.

You should [make an RPC call to the server](http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html). The server callback should fetch the data from your database, and send it back to your GWT client.

Answer (score 2):

Using Eclipse with the google plugin, you can create a new "Web Application Project". More information about the plugin can be found here: http://code.google.com/eclipse/

You will get a simple project that contains a GreetingService which receives a String from the client side and responds with "Hello" + string. For your example you would have to add the code that reads from the DB in the GreetingServiceImpl class and then use the response (which can be a String[] containing the name read from DB) on the client side to populate the SuggestionBox